# Can't add data to hash map declared within non-activity class

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-studio

I have declared a hash map within a non-activity class as follows:

```
public class Wifi {
    HashMap<String, String> AccessPoints = new HashMap<String, String>();
    AccessPoints.put("AP1", "first_ap");

    public ArrayList<Integer> scanWifi(Context context) {
            // code here
    }
}
```

I then tried to add data to the hash map but I get a "cannot resolve symbol" error in Android Studio.

When I place `AccessPoints.put("AP1", "first_ap");` within a function in the class it appears to work.

Comment: Put more code like where are you declare map and accessing it? it seems scope related problem.

Comment: @EldarMensutov The message is "cannot resolve symbol 'put'"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
AccessPoints.put("AP1", "first_ap");
```

Invoking a method should be done within a block of:

- a method.
- a static initializer.
- an instance initializer.
- a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a small starting letter for variables in Java. It might consider the AccessPoint a new class, although it is only a name of a declared variable.
Try changing the first letter in the name and it might help.

```
HashMap<String, String> accessPoints = new HashMap<String, String>();
    accessPoints.put("api","first");
```

If it does not help, it might be a scope problem so add more context to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This map is probably a member of some class. You didn't specify where it's defined.
If you want to access it from another class, you should make it accessible to other classes (by making it public), and by accessing it with the reference of the object in which it was created.

For example :

```
class X {
   ...
   public HashMap<String, String> accessPoints = new HashMap<String, String>();
   ...
}

class Y {

...
   X xObj = new X();
   xObj.accessPoints.put ("fff","yyy");
...
}
```

Of course it would be better, object oriented wise, to make the map private, and access it from other classes via methods.

```
class X {
   ...
   private HashMap<String, String> accessPoints = new HashMap<String, String>();
   ...
   public void addAccessPoint (String key, String value) {
       accessPoints.put(key,value);
   }
}

class Y {

...
   X xObj = new X();
   xObj.addAccessPoint ("fff","yyy");
...
}
```